# Removing default gravity in "world". Planetary gravity simulation

Tags: physics, blend4web

How to remove the gravity in scenes (or world) in Blend4Web?

I already used `m_phy.apply_force_world(obj, fx_world, fy_world, fz_world)`, and `m_phy.set_gravity(obj, gravity)`, but still the balls I added to the scenes always fall.

I am making simulation of planetary gravity, so I need gravity of zero.

If I make the object "static" in order not to fall, can it be moved by `m_phy.apply_force`?? And will it be affected by collision?

Comment: Not sure if you'll be able to get any quality answers here, maybe you'll get a faster response over at [Blend4Web Forum](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums/) since most devs hang out there